# How to crop the test properly using ellipsis

Tags: html, ellipsis

I have a html like follows:

```
<td>
                 <h6 style="width:80px;text-overflow:ellipsis;" title="${name}"><span class="badge badge-info">${name}</span></h6>

</td>
```

How to show the text as dotted if the text is bigger in size than the show area. ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `overflow: hidden` for `text-overflow:ellipsis` to work – otherwise the content will just flow out of the element and not be cut off.

Answer (score 0):

For `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to work, you need to specify `overflow: hidden;` and `white-space: nowrap;` as well.

i.e.

```
... style="width:80px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;" ...
```

BTW, i suggest you move out that inline style (and other inline styles) into a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

it should be :-

```
<td>
<h6 style="width:80px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden" title="${name}"><span class="badge badge-info">${name}</span></h6>
</td>
```